# Invoking reflection APIs correctly - Android

Tags: java, android, reflection, webview

I am trying to invoke the `getSelection` method of `WebView`. I am trying to use the reflection APIs in Android to get the selected text.

I have extended `WebView` (the new class is named `MyWebView`) to add some functionality. The method `getSelection` is invoked like so within `MyWebView`:

```
for(Method m : WebView.class.getDeclaredMethods()) {
    if(m.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("getSelection")) {
        m.setAccessible(true);
        String str;
        try {
            Log.v(this.toString(), "is getSelection available? " + m.getModifiers() + " " + m.isAccessible());
            str = (String) m.invoke(this, new Object[] { null });
            Log.v(this.toString(), "String selected = " + str);
            Toast.makeText(context, str, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

`MyWebView` is a non-Activity class. Running the code results in the following `LogCat` output:

```
08-16 19:15:22.745: W/System.err(23452): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: object is not an instance of the class
08-16 19:15:22.745: W/System.err(23452):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-16 19:15:22.745: W/System.err(23452):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
08-16 19:15:22.745: W/System.err(23452):    at com.englishhelper.bluebottle.EHWebView$3.onTouch(EHWebView.java:210)
08-16 19:15:22.745: W/System.err(23452):    at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:3934)
08-16 19:15:22.745: W/System.err(23452):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:903)
08-16 19:15:22.745: W/System.err(23452):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:942)
08-16 19:15:22.745: W/System.err(23452):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:942)
08-16 19:15:22.745: W/System.err(23452):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:942)
08-16 19:15:22.745: W/System.err(23452):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:942)
08-16 19:15:22.745: W/System.err(23452):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1730)
08-16 19:15:22.745: W/System.err(23452):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1142)
08-16 19:15:22.745: W/System.err(23452):    at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2102)
08-16 19:15:22.745: W/System.err(23452):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1714)
08-16 19:15:22.745: W/System.err(23452):    at android.view.ViewRoot.deliverPointerEvent(ViewRoot.java:2218)
08-16 19:15:22.745: W/System.err(23452):    at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1889)
08-16 19:15:22.745: W/System.err(23452):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-16 19:15:22.745: W/System.err(23452):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
08-16 19:15:22.745: W/System.err(23452):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3691)
08-16 19:15:22.745: W/System.err(23452):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-16 19:15:22.745: W/System.err(23452):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
08-16 19:15:22.745: W/System.err(23452):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:847)
08-16 19:15:22.745: W/System.err(23452):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:605)
08-16 19:15:22.745: W/System.err(23452):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

My question is:
1. The `invoke` method in the Reflection API requires that I pass the object of the class on which I intend to call the method on as the first argument. In this case, it would be an object of class `MyWebView`. How do I call `invoke` with an object of type `MyWebView`?
2. The same code works well in a case where `MyWebView` is part of the `Activity` class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The exception shows that you are inside of an anonymous inner class. The problem is that you are accidentally passing the instance of the inner class instead of the instance of `EHWebView`.

You can tell that you are inside of an inner class because after the normal class name `EHWebView`, you see a `$3`, which simply refers to the 3rd anonymous inner class of `EHWebView`. Here is the relevant part of the stack trace you posed:

```
08-16 19:15:22.745: W/System.err(23452):    at com.englishhelper.bluebottle.EHWebView$3.onTouch(EHWebView.java:210)
```

Typically, anonymous inner classes are event handlers or runnables. They appear often and many people are not even aware they are using them.

You are passing `this` to the `invoke()` method. Inside of an inner class, `this` refers to the instance of that inner class instead of the instance of the outer class `EHWebView`.

To solve the problem, pass the reference of the outer class by removing `this` an instead using `EHWebView.this`:

```
        str = (String) m.invoke(EHWebView.this, new Object[] { null });
```