# In Android, how to invoke sun.misc.Unsafe methods using Java reflection?

Tags: java, android, reflection, dalvik

Although there are similar questions (such as [A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8843953/how-to-invoke-method-with-variable-arguments-in-java-using-reflection), [B](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20925962/how-to-invoke-a-method-using-reflection) and [C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18274891/invoking-reflection-apis-correctly-android)), their answers do not solve my problem.

I am using Android Studio 1.5.1 targeting Android API 18 (before Android KitKat 4.4, so I’m dealing with Dalvik, not ART runtime).

**My questions are:**

(1) When I use the following code, I can print a list of all [sun.misc.Unsafe methods available in Android](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/libcore/+/9edf43dfcc35c761d97eb9156ac4254152ddbc55/libdvm/src/main/java/sun/misc/Unsafe.java), so I think I have access to them using **reflection** but I do not know how to call them using **reflection**.

(2) If (1) is possible, how to find the magicNumber (in the code below) address using sun.misc.Unsafe methods in Android via reflection?

(3) If (1) is possible but (2) is not possible, how to put an integer number (say int test=123) in any native memory address and print its memory address using sun.misc.Unsafe methods in Android via reflection?

```
        String ClassName = "sun.misc.Unsafe";
        int magicNumber = 0x23420023 ;
    try {
        Class classToInvestigate = Class.forName(ClassName);
        Constructor[] aClassConstructors = classToInvestigate.getDeclaredConstructors();
        for(Constructor c : aClassConstructors){
            System.out.println("********************* constructor="+c);
        }

        Method[] aClassMethods = classToInvestigate.getDeclaredMethods();
        for(Method m : aClassMethods){
            System.out.println("********************* method="+m);

        }
        Field theUnsafe = classToInvestigate.getDeclaredField("THE_ONE");
        theUnsafe.setAccessible(true);
        Object unsafe = theUnsafe.get(null);

    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        // Class not found!
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        // Unknown exception
    }
```

Comment: I don't see any method in `Unsafe` that will let you get the address of a local variable, and I fail to see the relevance of any of your cited questions, especially the C# one.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately `sun.misc.Unsafe` class not included in android standard library and you should use it between reflection but I found another solution: to use it between pre-compiled direct proxy class from my library: https://github.com/iamironz/unsafe

Answer (score -3):

This class will return you an Unsafe instance on almost all existing JVM implementations including Android (both VM versions): https://github.com/noctarius/tengi/blob/master/java/tengi-core/src/main/java/com/noctarius/tengi/core/impl/UnsafeUtil.java

Comment: Can you give the steps how to include UnsafeUtil.java in my app using Android Studio? I mean do I need to copy it some folder and how to include it in my Android Studio project?

Comment: Just copy the source to some class

Comment: Copying the source into some class does not work, it gives me three errors in Android Studio:  (1) unexpected token for: package com.noctarius.tengi.core.impl;  (2) cannot resolve symbol: import com.noctarius.tengi.core.model.Identifier; and  (3) cannot resolve symbol: import sun.misc.Unsafe;

Comment: If I remove **import sun.misc.Unsafe** which is the most important item, nothing works.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it is an Android Studio thing to "prevent" access to sun.misc.Unsafe. Have you tried to compile on command line?