# How to import sun.misc.Unsafe in android studio?

Tags: java, android-studio

I am trying to use protobuf3 source code and it uses "sun.misc.Unsafe". Can you please let me know how to import the necessary package for it.[Here is the sample code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mjrrb.jpg)

Comment: Rephrased the question for readability.

Answer (score 0):

This class will return you an Unsafe instance on almost all existing JVM implementations including Android (both VM versions): https://github.com/noctarius/tengi/blob/master/java/tengi-core/src/main/java/com/noctarius/tengi/core/impl/UnsafeUtil.java

this answer is a copy of noctarius' answer here:
[In Android, how to invoke sun.misc.Unsafe methods using Java reflection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34702403/in-android-how-to-invoke-sun-misc-unsafe-methods-using-java-reflection)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately `sun.misc.Unsafe` class not included in android standard library. But you can to use it between pre-compiled direct proxy class: https://github.com/iamironz/unsafe